# Recursive Function for drawing a tree in Turtle

Tags: python, function, recursion, tree, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a tree using a recursive function. Here is my best shot. I know I am far off but am having trouble trying to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def svTree( trunkLength, levels ):
    """ uses the turtle drawing functions to return a tree with a specified number of levels
    input: two integers, trunkLength and levels
    """

    newtrunkLength = trunkLength *.5

    if levels ==1:
           penup()
    else:

        forward(trunkLength)       
        left(45)         
        svTree(trunkLength * 0.5,levels -1)      
        right(90)
        forward(trunkLength *.5)
        svTree(trunkLength * 0.5,levels -1)      
        left(45)          
        backward(trunkLength)

        forward(trunkLength)       
        right(45)
        svTree(trunkLength * 0.5,levels -1)
        left(90)
        svTree(trunkLength * 0.5,levels -1)
        right(45)
        backward(trunkLength)

        return  svTree(newtrunkLength,levels -1)
```

Here is my new attempt at it: I think it is closer as I can make the Y but then I think my recursive step is flawed... Please help! Thank you! :)

```
def svTree( trunkLength, levels ):
    """ uses the turtle drawing functions to return a tree with a specified number of levels
    input: two integers, trunkLength and levels
    """

    newtrunkLength = trunkLength *.5

    if levels ==1:
           penup()
    else:

        forward(trunkLength)       
        left(45)         
        forward(trunkLength * 0.5)
        penup()
        backward(trunkLength * 0.5)
        right(90)
        pendown()
        forward(trunkLength *.5)
        penup()
        backward(trunkLength *.5)
        right(180)
        left(45)
        right(180)
        return svTree(newtrunkLength,levels-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy-paste is a good indication that you are doing something wrong. Factor out repeating parts.

Most likely, you do not want to draw while backing up, so call `penup()` before `backward()`.

Also, you want all subtrees to grow from the same point, so you need to get back after each recursive call.

Finally, you never use the value returned, so what a recursive call in a `return` line tries to achieve?

Comment: okay I think this is closer: I can make the first Y but then my recursive step is messed up...
def svTree( trunkLength, levels ):
  newtrunkLength = trunkLength *.5

    if levels ==1:
           penup()
    else:

        forward(trunkLength)       
        left(45)         
        forward(trunkLength * 0.5)
        penup()
        backward(trunkLength * 0.5)
        right(90)
        pendown()
        forward(trunkLength *.5)
        penup()
        backward(trunkLength *.5)
        right(180)
        left(45)
        right(180)
        return svTree(newtrunkLength,levels-1)